# Программно открыть вкладку в BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

Есть TabLayout с вкладками. Программно открыть эти вкладки можно так:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
        new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

//Связывание ViewPager с TabLayout
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
и далее:
pager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

На одной из вкладок реализована BottomNavigationView с тремя пунктами, по нажатии на которые загружаются фрагменты вот так:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bottomReports:
                MainActivity.currentScreen = "Reports";
                Utilities.ruleSearch(false);
                loadFragment(frmReports.newInstance());
                return true;
            ...
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Нужно программно перейти на вкладку bottomReports. Перейти на нее указанным выше способом невозможно, т.к. в pager вновь создаваемые вкладки не попадают. Этим способом удается перейти только на материнский фрагмент в котором расположен BottomNavigationView.
Вопрос: как программно открыть вкладку bottomReports?

Answer (score 0):

Для программного выбора нужно сделать так:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bottomReports);
```

но делать это нужно после инициализации менюшки. Вот есть [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202294/set-selected-item-in-android-bottomnavigationview)

Comment: я делал так, как Вы предлагаете:
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
                     bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_panel_analysis);
                     bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bottomHistory);
Но получаю ошибку, как в этом вопросе:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459925/set-selected-item-in-bottomnavigationview-null-object-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: вообще по логике у меня например сначала обьявил виджет, потом засетил к нему менюшку а потом селект сделал, допускаю что вы пытаетесь выбрать то чего нету

Comment: вот меня смущает приватность `private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` этого слушателя. у вас есть строка где вы этот слушатель привязываете к виджету?

Comment: Вот так он объявлен в том же классе:
View rootViewAnalysis  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frm_analysis, container, false);
        BottomNavigationView navigationAnalysis = (BottomNavigationView) rootViewAnalysis.findViewById(R.id.bottom_panel_analysis);
        navigationAnalysis.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

Comment: а если после привязки слушателя проводить выбор элемента, если мне не изменяет память то там при программном селекте именно он и вызвается

Comment: мне нужно вызвать открытие вкладки из MainActivity, а вкладка находится во фрагменте. Слушатель тоже во фрагменте. Проблема в том, как вызвать из MainActivity событие во фрагменте и не нарваться на null pointer.

Comment: ну например можно через интерфейс передать что-то

Comment: Пример бы какой-нибудь увидеть, все кажется уже перепробовал.

Comment: вы можете передать индекс элемента меню на который нужно перейти через bundle или такой вариант тоже не подходит?

Comment: Дело в том, что это будет индекс элемента меню в пределах BottomNavigationView. 
А открываю я этот пункт из MainActivity, в котором есть свое меню, в одном из пунктов этого меню (во фрагменте) и расположено BottomNavigationView.
Т.е. мне нужно открыть пункт меню, содержащий BottomNavigationView (это я могу: pager.setCurrentItem(...)) и после этого открыть пункт в BottomNavigationView. Вопрос, как это сделать?
Я надеялся, что есть какой-то штатный метод для обращения к пунктам вложенного таким образом меню, но ничего работающего не нашел.

Comment: что-то я если честно запутался)) у вас есть активность с меню (не понятно каким) из этого меню вы открываете фрагмент, если я правильно понял вы можете открыть фрагмент с менюшкой из меню которое в активности, но у вас сложности с открытием определенного пункта меню в целевом фрагменте?

Comment: да Вы правильно поняли. У меня есть MainActivity. В ней есть TabLayout и ViewPager. В ViewPager находится несколько страниц в виде фрагментов. В одном из этих фрагментов есть нижнее меню BottomNavigationView при выборе пункта которого в ViewPager загружается соответствующий этому пункту фрагмент. В MainActivity у меня реализован поиск по вкладкам. Когда я открываю какую-то вкладку, то поиск осуществляется по данным на этой вкладке путем фильтрации данных, соответствующих поисковой строке.

Comment: Когда поиск завершается, то я программно открываю вкладку на которой происходил поиск. Если это вкладки, изначально находящиеся в  ViewPager, то все проходит нормально, я нахожу и открываю нужную вкладку pager.setCurrentItem(...), но если поиск происходит на вкладке загруженной по пункту меню BottomNavigationView, то я могу только программно открыть вкладку в которой находится BottomNavigationView, но не саму вкладку пункта меню. Вот в этом и проблема.

Comment: вот пример создания интерфейса для передачи данных - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121091/passing-data-from-activity-to-fragment-using-interface, суть проста - делаете прослойку между активностью и целевым фрагментом и при необходимости передаете данные